# Animal Sniffer Maven plugin fails to detect generics addition

Tags: java, maven, generics, animal-sniffer

The Maven Animal Sniffer plugin works great for detecting Java API signature changes unless the change is only addition of a generic type.  For instance, in Java 6 you have `JList` but in Java 7 you have `JList<E>`.  If I use the generic type parameter, it won't compile with JDK 6, but Animal Sniffer doesn't detect that.  If I compile with JDK 7 in my dev env,  I won't realize that I've broken the build until I commit the code and someone with JDK 6 tries to build it.

Sample Java code that should fail the sniff and the relevant part of my Maven configuration are below.  Help me prevent this tragedy.  :)  ***Is there something I can change so that Animal Sniffer will fail the build as expected?***

**Example.java**

```
import javax.swing.JList;

public class Example {
  // Only compiles with JDK 1.7+
  private final JList<String> aList = new JList<String>();
}
```

**Maven Build Configuration**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Make sure we generate the correct Java byte code. -->
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>animal-sniffer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Make sure we don't use incompatible Java APIs. -->
                <signature>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.signature</groupId>
                    <!-- See http://mojo.codehaus.org/signatures/ -->
                    <artifactId>java16</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1</version>
                </signature>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>sniff-jdk</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Seems like a good candidate for a new issue in [plugin's jira](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MANIMALSNIFFER).

Comment: @OlegEstekhin I don't have access to file an issue, and I don't see any way to get access or communicate with the developers.  :/

Comment: The home page at https://jira.codehaus.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa contains instructions on how to create a new account and an explanation why they make it so hard.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin Thanks for pointing me to the signup.  I hadn't thought to look at the dashboard.  I filed http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MANIMALSNIFFER-42.